# To link parameter with dynamic table in birt report

Tags: filter, parameter-passing, birt

I'm new in birt i have a data set. now i want project a table with one header with four sub columns
using that one data set
example: Students is header
Name Marks sub columns
but now i'm having one data set that has name and marks only so how can i include tha student with filter format

if anyone knows please guide me

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: yes.now i have a dynamic table is there any possible to connect with my parameter.

Comment: parameter means i have four parameter to view the report so i have to add a dynamic table so how can i connect with parameter that dynamic table

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. Maybe you should add a graphic to explain it.